# How to remove braces and its content except content inside vertical bar in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, regex

i have this String `{bc}{sx|lineage||}`, `{sx|ancestry||}` , i want to remove `{}` and its content, but do not want to delete content inside `| |`.

i tried below code but this is deleting {} and all its content including ||

```
"\\s?\\{.*?\\}"
```

Comment: What is the expected result for the `{bc}{sx|lineage||}` and `{sx|ancestry||}` strings?

Comment: Do you want to get `{bc}lineage` and `ancestry` as a result?

Comment: Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56786420/3832970) and let know which  solution works for you, I will add details then.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working. if I get this {bc}{sx|lineage||}, {sx|ancestry||}, good, {a_link|contrary}. And want "lineage, ancestry, good, contrary" as a result. can you please send me the pattern for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove `{bc}` completely and keep `lineage` and `ancestry` use

```
let str = "{bc}{sx|lineage||}, {sx|ancestry||}"
let pattern = "\\s*\\{[^{}|]*(?:\\|([^{}|]*)\\|{2})?\\}"
let result = str.replacingOccurrences(of: pattern, with: "$1", options: .regularExpression)
print(result)   // => lineage,ancestry
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NiEPZL/1).

If `{bc}` should be kept, I suggest using

```
let str = "{bc}{sx|lineage||}, {sx|ancestry||}"
let pattern = "\\s*\\{[^{}|]*\\|([^{}|]*)\\|{2}\\}"
let result = str.replacingOccurrences(of: pattern, with: "$1", options: .regularExpression)
print(result)   // => {bc}lineage,ancestry
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XQ6LU5/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working. if I get this {bc}{sx|lineage||}, {sx|ancestry||}, good, {a_link|contrary}. And want "lineage, ancestry, good, contrary" as a result. can you please send me the pattern for this.

Comment: @AquibAfzal Then use `pattern="\\s*\\{[^{}|]*(?:\\|([^{}|]*)\\|{2}|\\|([^{}|]*))?\\}"` and `with: "$1$2"`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/hgouxG/1). Is this the pattern you really searched for?

Answer (score 0):

To get the string between two strings `(in your case - "|")`, you can use the below method:

```
func getSubstringIn(_ str: String, from: String, to: String) -> String? {
    if let upperBound = str.range(of: from)?.upperBound,
        let lowerBound = str.range(of: to, range: upperBound..<str.endIndex)?.lowerBound {
        return String(str[upperBound..<lowerBound])
    }
    return nil
}
```

Usage:

`let s = getSubstringIn(test, from: "|", to: "|")`

For example 
String `{bc}{sx|lineage||}`, will return - `lineage`
and String `{sx|ancestry||}`, returns - `ancestry`